# Create, Start and Stop Sauce Connect Tunnel for parallel tests running on Sauce Labs?

Tags: java, maven, testng, saucelabs

I am running parallel tests on Sauce Labs using TestNG and Selenium. I found two sources: https://github.com/saucelabs/ci-sauce/tree/master/src/main/java/com/saucelabs/ci/sauceconnect and https://github.com/saucelabs/sauce-java/tree/master/sauce-connect-plugin/src/main/java/com/saucelabs/maven. However, I am not exactly sure how to implement these. I am new to Selenium and TestNg. Any help or advice would be appreciated. Please let me know if I need to provide any more information.

Answer (score 0):

First, is your AUT behind a firewall? If not, you don't require a SL tunnel.

However, if your application can only be access on your company's internal network, then I would suggest using a dedicated box (server) to run the tunnel on, the link below provides the minimum requirements based your VM number, in additional more details information around SL tunneling.

https://docs.saucelabs.com/reference/sauce-connect/